# Constructing weighted directed graphs of sub-matrices of a matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

This `code` performs as expected, but it is too scattered and I like to create, if possible, a `Mathematica` function `sayanTest[matrix_, excLst_]:=` to do the following by combining `Parts 1-4`:

```
ClearAll[dim, mat1, excLst, mat2, MMmat1, mat211, mat212, mat221, 
   mat222, mm0111, mm1011, mm1101, mm1110, nodes, wag];

multiplierB[M_?MatrixQ, 
   sec_Integer] := ((#/Tr[#] & /@ N[M\[Transpose]])\[Transpose] // 
   Take[#, sec, sec] & // Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sec] - #] &);  
select[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := 
   matrix*Map[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] &, matrix, {-1}];

(*Part 1*)
SeedRandom[14];
dim = 15;
mat1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {dim, dim}];
excLst = {5, 3, 1, 2, 4};  (*a specific order of rows and columns*)
MMmat1 = multiplierB[mat1, Length[excLst]];
mat2 = MMmat1[[excLst, excLst]];  (*ordered matrix*)

(*Part 2*)
(*create sub-matrices as block matrices of {5,3} and {1,2,4} *)
mat211 = Take[mat2, 2, 2];  
mat212 = Take[mat2, 2, -3];
mat221 = Take[mat2, -3, 2];
mat222 = Take[mat2, -3, -3];
(*substitute zeros in a sub-matrix*)
mm0111 = ArrayFlatten[{{0, mat212}, {mat221, mat222}}];
mm1011 = ArrayFlatten[{{mat211, 0}, {mat221, mat222}}];
mm1101 = ArrayFlatten[{{mat211, mat212}, {0, mat222}}];
mm1110 = ArrayFlatten[{{mat211, mat212}, {mat221, 0}}];

(*Part 3*)
(*create a weighted digraph using "mat2"*)
nodes = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
wam = select[mat2, .08, .12] /. {0. -> \[Infinity]};
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[nodes, wam];
HighlightGraph[wag, Subgraph[wag, {x5, x3}], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]

(*Part 4*)
Row[{
   wam2 = select[mm1011, .08, .11] /. {0. -> \[Infinity]};
   wag2 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[nodes, wam2];
   HighlightGraph[wag2, Subgraph[wag2, {x5, x3}], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"],
   wam3 = select[mm1101, .08, .11] /. {0. -> \[Infinity]};
   wag3 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[nodes, wam3];
   HighlightGraph[wag3, Subgraph[wag3, {x5, x3}], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
  }]
```

It will be ideal if the weighted digraphs are created with `fixed vertex coordinates` to make the comparison of the digraphs easy.

Comment: do you always break `excLst` into two parts (that is, do you need to get 4 matrices in step 2)?

Comment: in Part 3, shouldn't `select[mat2, .08, .12]` be `select[mm0111, .08, .12]`?

Comment: ... and looks like `nodes = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}` should be `nodes = {x5, x3, x1, x2, x4}` (to match the indices used to to get `mat2`)?

Comment: @kglr: Ideally, I want to break `excLst` into more than two parts. The choice of the number of breaks should be flexible. In a rare case that I actually have, the number goes to 100.

Comment: the function `parts12`  in my answer below allows arbitrary number of parts.

Comment: @kglr: In Part 3, `select[mat2,.08, .12]` is correct (sorry for my mistake in the title of Part 3, which I edited the post) because with `mat2` I wanted to see the graph of the full matrix without any zeros.

Comment: @kglr: Yes, you are right that the list of the `nodes` should be `nodes={x5,x3,x1,x2,x4}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Parts 1 & 2

```
ClearAll[waMs]
waMs[matrix_, indexlists_] := Module[{exclst = Flatten @ indexlists, 
   ll = Length @ indexlists, lengths = Length /@ indexlists, m2}, 
  m2 = multiplierB[matrix, Length[exclst]][[exclst, exclst]](* Part 1 *);
  Prepend[m2][ArrayFlatten[MapAt[0 &, TakeList[m2, lengths, lengths], #]] & /@ 
    Tuples[Range @ ll, 2]](*Part 2*)]
```

***Examples:***

Using `waMs[mat1, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}]` we get OP's `mat2`, `mm0111`, `mm1011`, `mm1101` and  `mm1110`:

```
{mat2, mm0111, mm1011, mm1101, mm1110} == waMs[mat1, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

In the `MatrixPlot`s below white cells show the 0 blocks:

```
Multicolumn[MatrixPlot /@ waMs[mat1, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}], 3, 
 Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

Using `{{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {6, 7, 8}}` as the second argument we get 10 matrices:

```
Partition[MatrixPlot /@ waMs[mat1, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {6, 7, 8}}], 5] // Grid
```

[image]

#### Parts 3 & 4

```
ClearAll[waGs]
waGs[lb_: .08, ub_: 0.12][mat_, indexlists_, hl_, vlabels_: Automatic,
   o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{wam = select[mat, lb, ub] /. 0. | 0 -> ∞, wag}, 
  wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vlabels, wam, VertexLabels -> "Name", o];
  HighlightGraph[wag, 
   Subgraph[wag, If[vlabels === Automatic, hl, vlabels[[hl]]]], 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]]
```

***Examples:***

```
wams = waMs[mat1, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}];

hl = {5, 3};

wg0 = waGs[][wams[[1]], {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}, hl, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

[image]

Using `waGs` with four of the input matrices produced by `parts12`:

```
wams = Rest[wams] ;


waGs[.08, .11][#, {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}, hl, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[wg0]] & /@
   wams // Grid[Partition[#, 2], Dividers -> All] &
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Use `hl = {1, 2, 4, 5}` to get

[image]

[image]

Further examples:

```
indexlsts = {{5, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {6, 7}};
hl = {1, 2, 4, 5};
vnames = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};

wams = waMs[mat1, indexlsts];

wg0 = waGs[][wams[[1]], indexlsts, hl, vnames]
```

[image]

```
waGs[.08, .11][#, indexlsts, hl, vnames, ImageSize -> 200, 
    VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[wg0]] & /@ wams // 
 Grid[Partition[#, 3], Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: One small question: how can I substitute in the above digraphs the generic nodes `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}` with ` {x1 -> "AGF", x2 -> "OIL", x3 -> "MA1", x4 -> "MA2",  x5 -> "EGW"}`? I tried few things but did not succed in.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, try `VertexReplace[graph, {x1 -> "AGF", x2 -> "OIL", x3 -> "MA1", x4 -> "MA2", x5 -> "EGW"}]`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I did `wg0 = VertexReplace[waGs[][wams[[1]], lockScenario, {6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 16}], v1]` where `v1` is the list of new vertex labels, the replacement of the new labels are done but the highlighted edges turn to `Default Blue`. I lose the red highlighted edges.

Comment: @Tugrul, I updated `waGs[]` to allow specifying vertex labels as the optional 4th argument.